# How to make User Form Output at the end of a column in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, user-interface, excel, userform

I'm trying to make this user form output option button results at the end of a column. Originally I tried using the same i in the for next loop that I have in my main module, but the user form wouldn't recognize the variable, even after dimensioning it as public. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub cmdOk_Click()

If opt1 Then
    Range(Range(“E3”), Range(“E3”).End(xlDown)) = "None"
ElseIf opt2 Then
    Range(Range(“E3”), Range(“E3”).End(xlDown)) = "3/8 Plain"
ElseIf opt3 Then
    Range(Range(“E3”), Range(“E3”).End(xlDown)) = "1/2 Plain"
ElseIf opt4 Then
    Range(Range(“E3”), Range(“E3”).End(xlDown)) = "1/2 Herringbone"
ElseIf opt5 Then
    Range(Range(“E3”), Range(“E3”).End(xlDown)) = "1/2 Diamond"
End If

Unload frmLagging

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the last row in that column and then write to it. Here is an example (**Untested**). You can read more about finding the last row [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    '~~> We add 1 so that we get the next empty cell
    lRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Set rng = .Range("E" & lRow)

    If opt1 Then
        rng.Value = "None"
    ElseIf opt2 Then
        rng.Value = "3/8 Plain"
    ElseIf opt3 Then
        rng.Value = "1/2 Plain"
    ElseIf opt4 Then
        rng.Value = "1/2 Herringbone"
    ElseIf opt5 Then
        rng.Value = "1/2 Diamond"
    End If
End With
Unload frmLagging
```

Answer (score 0):

Also,
Here is one of my favorite iif statements,

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, x
    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    Set Rng = Cells(Rws + 1, "E")

    x = IIf(Opt1, "None", IIf(Opt2, "3/8 Plain", IIf(Opt3, "1/2 Plain", IIf(Opt4, "1/2 Herringbone", IIf(Opt5, "1/2 Diamond", "Nada")))))
    Rng = x

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Adjusted code to place value in next empty cell in column A